# add code to core, how?

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, core

I want add 2 lines code into  but I want do this from my Extension
How can I do this job ?

**Don't want to add code to core file and then insert it into local folder**

Is this possible add directly into my extension ?

I want add 2 lines below into

> /code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

in the `public function estimatePostAction()`

under the `$region = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');`

Code is :

```
$cityDiff = $this->getRequest()->getParam('city');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEstimatedCity($cityDiff);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your requirement, if you expect you extension can work on further version I suggest you use Observer to listen Magento event then add data to core/session.

in your config.xml, define event listener. if you know the exactly event you want to listen, or listen all controller post dispatch.

```
<global>
<events>
    <controller_action_postdispatch>
        <observers>
            <controller_action_after>
                <class>YOUR_MODULE/observer</class>
                <method>listenControllerActionPostDispatch</method>
            </controller_action_after>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_postdispatch>

</events></global>
```

in your Model/Observer.php

```
class YOUDMOUDLE_Model_Observer {

public function listenControllerActionPostDispatch($observer)
{
    if($observer->getEvent()
        ->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'YOUR_TARGET')
    {
        $cityDiff = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('city');
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEstimatedCity($cityDiff);
    }

}
```

Comment: 'YOUR_TARGET' is for example `estimatePostAction` ? that code will like `->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'estimatePostAction')` or anything else ?

Comment: the fullActionName is following the route rule, for example cart page is checkout_cart_index, and your case might be checkout_cart_estimate_post

Comment: I have a file Observer in Model folder that use for another functions, added your code to it and code is `public function listenControllerActionPostDispatch($observer)
{
    if($observer->getEvent()
        ->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_estimate_post')
    {
        $cityDiff = $this->getRequest()->getParam('city');
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEstimatedCity($cityDiff);
    }

}` then added under my prev event in config.xml but nothing, seems your method is correct and I do wrong anything here! Is possible 2 observer function in one file ?

Comment: yes, you can have multiple method in one observer file. you can echo the actionName before go into your condition. make sure Event catch.

Comment: retrived `echo $this->getRequest()->getActionName();` and it show me "index" but when add index to observer in getFullActionName then got error

Comment: Finally work, thank you for your guide, but must use `Mage::app()` instead of `$this` in observer php file, also fullActionName is : `checkout_cart_estimatePost`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but think it would be something like this - anyway hopefully gets you on the right track:

`Mage_Checkout_CartController_New extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
      /**
      * Initialize shipping information
      */
     public function estimatePostAction()
     {
         $country    = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('country_id');
         $postcode   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_postcode');
         $city       = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_city');
         $regionId   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region_id');
         $region     = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');
         $cityDiff = $this->getRequest()->getParam('city');
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEstimatedCity($cityDiff);
         $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
             ->setCountryId($country)
             ->setCity($city)
             ->setPostcode($postcode)
             ->setRegionId($regionId)
             ->setRegion($region)
             ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
         $this->_getQuote()->save();
         $this->_goBack();
     }
}`

Sometimes config XML also needs to be told about the new overriding class?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14103/